# Collection with additional column to %ROWTYPE columns (two-way MINUS comparing two data sets)

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am looking for a way to create collection that would have one additional column that the source table/view columns referred by %ROWTYPE for simplicity.

```
TYPE my_type IS RECORD ( mode varchar2(10), some_table%ROWTYPE );
```

Goal:

I want to compare a table and its source view with a two-way MINUS operation and read source view once:

```
WITH src AS ( select ... from aView )
select * from (
select 'INSERT' as mode, a.* from (
select ... from src
MINUS
select ... from aTable ) a
UNION ALL
select 'DELETE' as mode, b.* from (
select ... from aTable
MINUS
select ... from src) b
)

( where ... is a <fixed_columns_list> )
```

I am starting to think of creating global temporary tables (GTTs) for INSERT and DELETE mode performed with INSERT ALL, but I have 25 tables, so that will add 50 GTTs :-/

Another con with GTTs is that whenever `aTable` is changed (new columns, renames, drops), I will also have to change respective GTT.

However, because GTTs will serve for temporary storage in this scenario, I can re-create them on demand automatically, so no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put the query in a `CURSOR` and use the `%ROWTYPE` of that cursor.

```
Declare
  CURSOR C is select * from something;

  C_nt is table of C%rowtype;

...
```

**NOTE** From my experience,  those `a.*` don't always match up to those `b.*`. I've always had to declare the columns.

Comment: I am having column list from metadata for any purpose where column order is risky. %ROWTYPE on a declared cursor doesn't help here, becuase `from something` has to be declared in cursor declaration.